# error while loading shared libraries: libboost_thread.so.1.54.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Tags: linux, c++, qt

I am trying to connect MongoDb with Qt c++. When I build it there is no error, just information like;

> :-1: warning: libboost_system.so.1.54.0, needed by
>   /usr/local/lib/libboost_thread.so, may conflict with
>   libboost_system.so.5

However when I tried to Run it says:

> error while loading shared libraries: libboost_thread.so.1.54.0:
>   cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Here is my small code sample which everything looks fine.

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"

#include <QDebug>
#include <mongo/client/dbclient.h>


MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);

    try
    {
        mongo::DBClientConnection c;
        c.connect("localhost");

        qDebug() << "Connected to Mongo";
    }
    catch (mongo::DBException &e)
    {
        qDebug() << "Cannot, Error : " << e.what();
    }

}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}
```

Could you please help me why I am getting this error and how to fix it ?

**EDIT :**

Here is also my .pro file ;

```
QT       += core gui

greaterThan(QT_MAJOR_VERSION, 4): QT += widgets

TARGET = mongodbtest
TEMPLATE = app


SOURCES += main.cpp\
        mainwindow.cpp

HEADERS  += mainwindow.h

FORMS    += mainwindow.ui

INCLUDEPATH += /usr/local/lib/

LIBS += -pthread \
    -lmongoclient \
    -lboost_thread \
    -lboost_system \
    -lboost_regex
```

and I see that I already have libboost_thread.so.1.54.0

> [mg@mg-CentOS mg]$ locate libboost_thread.so.1.54.0
>   /usr/local/lib/libboost_thread.so.1.54.0

Comment: Does $LD_LIBRARY_PATH includes  /usr/local/lib/ ?

Comment: what is the value of `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`?

Comment: I set `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` but it says same.. While build there is no error just information, however in Run step it gives error. Sorry for mistyping before.. I editted my question

Comment: can you remove `lboost_thread` from `LIBS` and check?

Comment: @Thushi When I remove it. In build step I get undefined errors (`/usr/local/include/boost/system/error_code.hpp:222: error: undefined reference to `boost::system::generic_category()'`) and `:-1: error: collect2: ld returned 1 exit status`

Comment: Oh yeah sorry . It is the problem with the version mismatch of `libboost_system.so`. It clearly says `libboost_system.so.1.54.0,` is required by `libboost_thread.so` but you are having the version `libboost_system.so.5`

Comment: In your sources do you have direct dependency on `libboost_system`?

Comment: @Thushi But I have also `libboost_system.so.1.54.0` in `/usr/local/lib/` in my include I have `#include <mongo/client/dbclient.h>` so maybe yes I am not sure

Comment: @goGud: Yes, you have both the version.Uninstall the old version

Comment: @Thushi thank you for your help, I solved problem with environment setting inside build step of QT

Comment: Ok.Sounds good. Post that as an answer.